# logback file inclusion depends on sequence of the content

Tags: slf4j, logback

logback [file inclusion](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#fileInclusion) is expecting configuration in sequence. I excluded the root and kept it under `${catalina.base}/conf/includedConfig.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<included>
  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
  </root>
</included>
```

And logback.xml under src/main/resources

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <include file="${catalina.base}/conf/includedConfig.xml"/>

 <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${catalina.base}/logs/logFile.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

It complains that it couldn't find appender. Although i changed the postion of  tag and kep it after appender, it complains the same error.

```
17:05:12,566 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Cou
ld not find an appender named [FILE]. Did you define it below instead of above in 
the configuration file?
```

If i do the same thing in reverse order i.e put appender in external file and root in logback.xml, it works fine.

The reason why i want to do this, i want to change the log level when build (same artifact) gets promoted to different environment, which will not be possible if log level is in application war.

Answer (score 0):

try to add  after  
like this:`

```
<appender name="all_info" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
      <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <FileNamePattern>./log/mylog_all_info.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
        <MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <MaxFileSize>5MB</MaxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{80} - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<root>
    <appender-ref ref="all_info" level="INFO" />
</root>
```

`